# I keep getting an string returned null...

Tags: java, arrays, image, imageicon

I really do not know what im doing wrong. I am making a state game so i can help people study but when i run it it works but it will not return an image onto the screen. This is the main bit of code where i have my array...

```
public void checkCorrectValue(String guess){
    if(guess.equalsIgnoreCase(current_state)){
        correct_value = true;
    }else{
        correct_value = false;
    }
}
public void setRandomState(){
    r = new Random();
    int i;
    i = r.nextInt(50);
    System.out.println(i);
    current_state = states[i];
    System.out.println(current_state + " was randomly selected");
}
public String getCurrentState(){
    return current_state;
}
public boolean isStateCorrect(){
    return correct_value;
}
```

I added my array called states and filled it with all the states. It does successfully output the right state so i know this works. And this is my panel code...

```
    States_Images us_img;
USA_States us_state;

public Menu(){
    setLayout(null);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    us_img = new States_Images();
    us_state = new USA_States();

    us_state.setRandomState();
    System.out.println(us_state.getCurrentState());

    JLabel l = new JLabel();
    l.setIcon(us_img.getCurrentStateImage());
    l.setBounds(0,0,500,500);
    add(l);
}
```

all it does is set my panel things then try to out put the image by first calling setRandomState() which sets the random state, it does out put correctly there. But when the us_img.getCurrentStateImage() is run...

```
    private ImageIcon currentstate_image;
private String current_state;
USA_States us_states;

public States_Images(){
    us_states = new USA_States();
}

public ImageIcon getCurrentStateImage(){
    setStateName();
    currentstate_image = new ImageIcon("graphics\\" + current_state + ".png");
    System.out.println(current_state + " image loaded");
    return currentstate_image;
}
private void setStateName(){
    current_state = us_states.getCurrentState();
}
```

It prints out "null image loaded". Then nothing shows on my frame. I really have no idea what im doing wrong as i have done things like this before. I know this is basic java so any help would really be appriciated!!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: This depends on where the images are stored.  From you code, it says that the images are stored on disk at `.\graphics\{name}.png` on the disk. 1- Do they exist? 2- Are they suppose to be embedded?

Comment: I know the images exist because i have called them "manually" straight in the menu code to the JLabel. So i know the images can be loaded in and displayed.

Comment: Then I would make sure that the `String` `current_state` matches that of the name of the image and the variable is set correctly

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) The image should probably be accessed as an [tag:embedded-resource] (by `URL`) instead of the code trying to load a `File`. 3) It is likely the current directory has changed between *"have called them "manually" straight in the menu code"* in the IDE and this use.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you aren't passing a valid filename while creating a new instance of ImageIcon.

```
currentstate_image = new ImageIcon("graphics\\" + current_state + ".png");
```

According to the [ImageIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) javadoc, you are required to pass filename(path) of the ImageIcon that you want to create.

You might want to make sure that the file actually exists under `./graphics/{current_state}.png`

Also, the javadoc says to use forward-slash whenever possible.

**EDIT**

```
System.out.println(current_state + " image loaded");
```

Have you checked if your `current_state` isn't null at this point? 
If you are getting  "null image loaded", it means that the `current_state` variable is `null`. Check your `us_states.getCurrentState();` method.

Posting your `USA_States` class might also help.

If you are trying to use the same `us_states` instance from the `Menu` class above, 
you will have to pass on the `us_states` from Menu class to the `States_Images` class.

Here's the modified code:
Menu class:

```
public Menu(){
    setLayout(null);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    us_state = new USA_States();
    us_state.setRandomState();

    us_img = new States_Images(us_state); //Pass us_state to States_Images
    System.out.println(us_state.getCurrentState());

    JLabel l = new JLabel();
    l.setIcon(us_img.getCurrentStateImage());
    l.setBounds(0,0,500,500);
    add(l);
}
```

States_Images class:

```
private ImageIcon currentstate_image;
private String current_state;
USA_States us_states;

public States_Images(USA_States us_state){
    this.us_states = us_state
}

public ImageIcon getCurrentStateImage(){
    setStateName();
    currentstate_image = new ImageIcon("graphics\\" + current_state + ".png");
    System.out.println(current_state + " image loaded");
    return currentstate_image;
}
private void setStateName(){
    current_state = us_states.getCurrentState();
}
```

Comment: I did that and when i run it still says null image loaded in the getCurrentStateImage() method. And i got the image part right because i can "manually" load the image into the jlabel in the menu class